# How to group variables that falls within a range of numbers

Tags: r, dplyr

I a df like this

```
my_df <- data.frame(
    b1 = c(2, 6, 3, 6, 4, 2, 1, 9, NA), 
    b2 = c(100, 4, 106, 102, 6, 6, 1, 1, 7), 
    b3 = c(75, 79, 8, 0, 2, 3, 9, 5, 80), 
    b4 = c(NA, 6, NA, 10, 12, 8, 3, 6, 2),
    b5 = c(2, 12, 1, 7, 8, 5, 5, 6, NA),
    b6 = c(9, 2, 4, 6, 7, 6, 6, 7, 9),
    b7 = c(1, 3, 7, 7, 4, 2, 2, 9, 5),
    b8 = c(NA, 8, 4, 5, 1, 4, 1, 3, 6),
    b9 = c(4, 5, 7, 9, 5, 1, 1, 2, 12))
```

I wanted to create a new column (NEW) based on the following assumptions.

If b9 is <= 2 write yellow.
If b9 is between 4 and 7 write white.
If b9 is >= 9 write green

The idea is to create something like this.

```
my_df1 <- data.frame(
        b1 = c(2, 6, 3, 6, 4, 2, 1, 9, NA), 
        b2 = c(100, 4, 106, 102, 6, 6, 1, 1, 7), 
        b3 = c(75, 79, 8, 0, 2, 3, 9, 5, 80), 
        b4 = c(NA, 6, NA, 10, 12, 8, 3, 6, 2),
        b5 = c(2, 12, 1, 7, 8, 5, 5, 6, NA),
        b6 = c(9, 2, 4, 6, 7, 6, 6, 7, 9),
        b7 = c(1, 3, 7, 7, 4, 2, 2, 9, 5),
        b8 = c(NA, 8, 4, 5, 1, 4, 1, 3, 6),
        b9 = c(4, 5, 7, 9, 5, 1, 1, 2, 12),
        NEW = c("white", "white", "white", "green", "white", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", "green"))
```

I thought something like this will do it, but it didn't.

```
greater_threshold <- 2
greater_threshold1 <- 4
greater_threshold2 <- 7
greater_threshold3 <- 9

my_df1 <- my_df %>%
    mutate(NEW = case_when(b9 <= greater_threshold ~ "yellow", b9 >= greater_threshold1 | b9 <= greater_threshold2 ~ "white", b9 >= greater_threshold3 ~ "green"))
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You should use ***and*** `&` instead of ***or*** `|` when assigning "white". Try `my_df %>% mutate(NEW = case_when(b9 <= greater_threshold ~ "yellow", b9 >= greater_threshold1 & b9 <= greater_threshold2 ~ "white", b9 >= greater_threshold3 ~ "green"))`

Comment: Excellent. Yes you are right. Using or instead of and was the issue. solved now.

Comment: What about the numbers in between the cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `between` from `dplyr`:

```
my_df %>%
  mutate(NEW = case_when(
    b9 <= 2 ~ "Yellow",
    between(b9, 4, 7) ~ "white",
    b9 >= 9 ~ "green"
  ))
```

Output:

```
  b1  b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 b7 b8 b9    NEW
1  2 100 75 NA  2  9  1 NA  4  white
2  6   4 79  6 12  2  3  8  5  white
3  3 106  8 NA  1  4  7  4  7  white
4  6 102  0 10  7  6  7  5  9  green
5  4   6  2 12  8  7  4  1  5  white
6  2   6  3  8  5  6  2  4  1 Yellow
7  1   1  9  3  5  6  2  1  1 Yellow
8  9   1  5  6  6  7  9  3  2 Yellow
9 NA   7 80  2 NA  9  5  6 12  green
```

Those not falling within the conditions (ie, 8) will be `NA`

Answer (score 1):

Your setup has some issues, for example what say you want would leave no label when b9 equals 3 or 8:

> If b9 is <= 2 write yellow. If b9 is between 4 and 7 write white. If
> b9 is >= 9 write green

I'm going to change the "white" condition to label b9 between 3 and 7, and "green" to >= 8, to maintain sanity. Then this should work:

```
greater_threshold1 <- 2
greater_threshold2 <- 7

my_df <- mutate(my_df,
                NEW = case_when(
                  b9 > greater_threshold2 ~ 'green',
                  b9 > greater_threshold1 ~ 'white',
                  TRUE ~ 'yellow'
                )) %>% print()
```

Output:

```
  b1  b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 b7 b8 b9    NEW
1  2 100 75 NA  2  9  1 NA  4  white
2  6   4 79  6 12  2  3  8  5  white
3  3 106  8 NA  1  4  7  4  7  white
4  6 102  0 10  7  6  7  5  9  green
5  4   6  2 12  8  7  4  1  5  white
6  2   6  3  8  5  6  2  4  1 yellow
7  1   1  9  3  5  6  2  1  1 yellow
8  9   1  5  6  6  7  9  3  2 yellow
9 NA   7 80  2 NA  9  5  6 12  green
```

`case_when` works best if you start with the narrowest condition, and then move wider as you go down the list of conditions - it executes the assignment operation as soon as it finds the condition that matches your variable, so you don't have to worry about the fact that, for example, `b9=12` would match both of the first two conditions - `case_when` won't even get past the first condition. Then you don't even have to define your most permissive condition, just use `TRUE` which basically means, if you've gotten this far, here's the assignment you are left with.

Your code goes backwards, so e.g. `b9=12` gets assigned "white" because it satisfies the second condition, `b9 >= greater_threshold1 | b9 <= greater_threshold2 ~ "white"`, and the assignment function never gets to the one you really want, `b9 >= greater_threshold3 ~ "green"`. Although you can also get what you want, I think, if you change the OR operator in the second condition to AND, i.e. `b9 >= greater_threshold1 & b9 <= greater_threshold2 ~ "white"`. If you use the narrow to wider condition approach that I describe, though, you don't need to mess with `&`, plus you get cleaner code.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `cut()` for this:

```
library(dplyr)

my_df %>%
  mutate(NEW = cut(b9, 
                   breaks = c(-Inf, 2, 4, 7, Inf),
                   labels = c("yellow", "white", "white", "green"),
                   include.lowest = TRUE))

  b1  b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 b7 b8 b9    NEW
1  2 100 75 NA  2  9  1 NA  4  white
2  6   4 79  6 12  2  3  8  5  white
3  3 106  8 NA  1  4  7  4  7  white
4  6 102  0 10  7  6  7  5  9  green
5  4   6  2 12  8  7  4  1  5  white
6  2   6  3  8  5  6  2  4  1 yellow
7  1   1  9  3  5  6  2  1  1 yellow
8  9   1  5  6  6  7  9  3  2 yellow
9 NA   7 80  2 NA  9  5  6 12  green
```